# In the Heat of the Moment

Tags: idioms

I'm trying to explain to someone why you can't say:

> In the heat of the moment Frank forgot to offer Beth a seat

I may even be wrong, but shouldn't you positively do something in the heat of the moment rather than nothing?

Please help out, and many thanks.

Comment: That sentence looks completely fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

In the heat of the moment **he forgot it**.  That's what he did, **he forgot**.  Even though there was no physical action involved, he did something: he forgot.

> - [**in the heat of the moment**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-heat-of-the-moment) - "If you say or do something in the heat of the moment, you say or do it without thinking because you are very angry or excited"

In this particular case Frank was so excited that **he forgot to offer his seat**.

References in literature ([from **TFD**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+heat+of+the+moment))

> - "Newman accompanied this very unusual outbreak with a violent blow upon the table, as if, in the heat of the moment, he had mistaken it for the chest or ribs of Mr Wackford Squeers."
> - "That he had thought he would have lots of time to put it in afterwards--when required--and, that, **in the heat of the moment, he had forgotten all about it**."